# SQL Server 2012/2014 insufficient memory available in the buffer pool

Tags: memory, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

We have bunch of SQL Server 2012 Standard and SQL Server 2014 Standard database instances running on Windows 2012, each have different storage and memory. We are getting

> Error Code: 802; There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool

from 3 database servers when we build large SQL Server indexes, and it's happening intermittently, once in 3 or 4 months. The same indexes run fine on servers with same version of SQL Server and only 1/3 of memory and CPU.

**SQL Server 2012 Standard**

Server1:  memory - 110GB allocated out of 128 GB version 11.0.6  - "Error Code: 802; There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool." reported when we run heavy index.

Server2:  memory -78GB allocated to SQL out of 96GB version 11.0.6  - "Error Code: 802; There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool." reported when we run heavy index.

Server: memory allocated 18GB out of 24GB. VM. No indexing error - 11.0.5

Server : memory 24GB out of 32GB. Physical. No indexing error - 11.0.5

**SQL Server 2014 Standard**

Server 1 : memory 56GB  out of 64GB physical memory version 12.0.5  - "Error Code: 802; There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool." reported when we run heavy index.

Server 2: memory 18GB out 24GB- VM – no indexing error - version 12.0.5.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: moved, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188031/sql-server-2012-2014-insufficient-memory-available-in-the-buffer-pool